# Install Linux guest on Windows host from .iso

Tags: vmware-server

I am using VMWare Server 1.0. I set the CD to point to the .iso file, then I start the VM and it starts to install.

I am on the summary screen. I have created a VM. I go to CD/DVD -> edit, change the radio button to Host Media, then I select ISO Image and Browse.

Here is the problem: in my browser I then get:

```
Inventory
  -> Virtual Machine (directory)
```

I don't know where that directory is. I have my ISOs in a folder on my desktop. I can't browse to my desktop. When I try to just put in a path, such as c:\mydesktop\mylinuxdirectory\linux1.iso, the following problems have been found:

> The ISO Image File Path must be a valid file path in the format: "[datastore] /path/to/isoimage.iso".

How do I browse to an ISO? I can add the iso after I start the VM, but by then it's too late and the VM says no operating system installed.

Answer (score 1):

After you login into the VMware Web Administration Interface select your "inventory" from the left box. Now in the box "Commands" in the right part of your screen you'll see an option "Add Datastore". Click on that and you'll be prompt to give a datastore name and the directory (path) of it. You can add the directory in which you keep your iso images.

Now you can find your iso images when you edit the CD/DVD option.

Answer (score 0):

Where is VMWare Server running?  On your machine, or another?

If it is on another machine, you may need to put the ISO on that server.  Then you can mount it before booting up the Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer VMWare 1. This is just reading from the error but have you tried changing the \ to /?

Alternatively, install a virtual drive, mount the ISO on that and use that as your VM's drive. That's how I use all my VMs.

Answer (score 0):

For me, if you look at the Relationships frame in the bottom right of the Summary tab, there is a Datastores field which is "(unavailable)".  Looks like it's a feature that I don't get with the free VMWare Server version..